# mySQL subquery/join across database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a result set of about 33 million records.

I need to remove any records based on another result set of about 10 million records based on an id.

This should take care of the problem, however since db1 is myISAM it's way too slow:

```
SELECT id
FROM db1.table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM db1.table2
) AS result
ORDER BY id
```

I have a second database that has the same data but InnoDB engine for the big 32 million result. Possible? This one is just a bit out of my league. Any/all suggestions welcome.

```
SELECT id
FROM db2.table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM db1.table2
) AS result
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as all databases exist on the same host - yes, this is no problem, you can join over more than one database (assuming you have sufficient privileges to access all those tables).

Wouldn't it be easier simply to try instead of asking here? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks you for the confirmation. I'm working with data I don't want to screw up and I'm out of my element on this one, so I want to research a little before I actually do anything...